# What is the difference in using '<Link>' from react-roouter-dom to a simple '<a href>' in combination with i18n?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-router-dom, i18next

I came across a behaviour that I cannot explain myself.

I am using the i18next library for a react project.
In this project I have a dropdown menu where I can select the language with `i18n.changeLanguage(lang)`
and all my text with `t("key")` are updated as expected.

However when I then change the page with `<a href="some link">` the state of the language is not saved and i18n goes back to the default language.

But when I use react-router-dom and the

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: "some link"
}}>
```

it keeps the state.

I know that I can pass state via `<Link>` like this (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)

```
<Link
    to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
    }}
/>
```

But I do not do this.
So why does he keep the State of i18n but not with ?
What am I missing?

And that you don't my question wrong: I want the described behaviour with `<Link>`. I just want to understand the difference behind it.

Comment: using the `<a href...` will reload the page. Using react-router's `Link` will update the URL without reloading the page. On page reload you will lose state and start over.

Comment: @BrianThompson thank you. That makes it clear